# Как сделать скриншот WebElement в SeleniumWebDriver на C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нашёл код - который имеет более 60 положительных оценок от пользователей - он делает скриншот элемента, но не как не могу его подвести под поледние правила c# и selenium - постоянно выдаёт ошибки при компиляции.

Вот оригинал , какие правки стоит внести ?

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));

// Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
    eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\images\\GoogleLogo_screenshot.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Answer (score 0):

Код не проверял, но должно сработать:

```
public Bitmap MakeElemScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, WebElement elem)
{
    var myScreenShotByteArr = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;

    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(myScreenShotByteArr));
    Bitmap elemScreenshot = screen.Clone(new Rectangle(elem.Location, elem.Size), screen.PixelFormat);

    screen.Dispose();

    return elemScreenshot;
}
```